# How do you run a from-scratch React app on Cloud9?

Tags: reactjs, aws-cloud9

So I'm obviously a beginner with React, this may be rambling and I and may be crucified, but I've been banging my head against a wall for the last week or so trying to build a hello world app from scratch using React on Cloud9.  I've read the official docs, and followed [this guide](https://blog.usejournal.com/creating-a-react-app-from-scratch-f3c693b84658) (and half a dozen others) contained within to no avail.  Using create-react-app does actually work, but I'd like to know what's going on under the hood.  I tried simply ejecting the app I made with CRA, but naturally as soon as I ejected it it stopped working.

I've cloned about 5 or 6 react boilerplates off Github, but none of them produce apps I can actually view in Cloud9, even those specifically configured for C9.  Almost all use webpack-dev-server, but even when I specifically flag it to use $IP, $PORT, $C9_HOSTNAME etc. like any other app I've deployed and it successfully compiles and tells me it's running, previewing the app or navigating to the URL returns a blank page or "Invalid Host Header."  Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the invalid host header issue, add this to your webpack config file:

```
devServer: {
  disableHostCheck: true
}
```

If you are still using `create-react-app`, then you should not be having that issue.

Comment: Don't have the 15 rep but I am upvoting you emotionally!

Answer (score 0):

Install all node modules required and create a 'myapp' as a project:

```
npm init react-app myapp

cd myapp
```

In order to start the app you need to set the process in environment port so go to `package.json` and change `script.start` to:

```
"start": "set PORT=process.env.PORT && react-scripts start"
```

Then do `npm start`, should work fine.